# Does anyone know the name of this tool on Mac OS?

Tags: macos

[image]

This looks like a file browser but I don't know name of the tool. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it just an ordinary Desktop view with smaller icons and labels on the right side?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, like Mateusz said, these look very much like file icons on a desktop.
If you want them displayed like that, right-click your desktop (two-finger-tap), and click on "Show View Options". That gived you a dialog that lets you adjust, how icons are displayed on your desktop. Try the settings from the following screenshot and play around with grid spacing, icon size and text size to get the exact desired result.

[image: desktop icon settings]

Comment: +1 TIP: to make a screenshot of a window, press ⌘+⇧+4 and then hit Space.

Comment: If this solves your question, can you 'accept' my answer, like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

This is Finder, it ships with every Mac.